# How to extract grouped results from an array inside a collection in Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am working with the Foursquare API using NodeJS and Mongodb on the backend side. I have all the user information and checkin history stored in a collection. So the collection looks similar to this:

```
{
    _id: ...,
    foursquareId: ...
    personalInfo: {},
    checkins: [
        {
            id: ...,
            createdAt: 123456789  //Seconds since epoch>,
            venue: {},
            ...
        },
        {
            id: ...,
            createdAt: 123456789  //Seconds since epoch>,
            venue: {},
            ...
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

For this question I am only interested to the checkins array. I need to return a list of checkins quantity by month and year, but I am not sure which is the best way to approach this. I think that the result would be something like this: (I am not totally convinced though)

```
{
    '2016': {
        'January': 43,
        'February': 38,
        'March': 40,
        'April': 48,
        'May': 50,
        'June': 41,
        'July': 39,
        'August': 38,
        'September': 30,
        'October': 29,
        'November': 38,
        'December': 41
    },
    '2017': {
        'January': 55,
        'February': 20
    }
}
```

I am not interested about the way I receive the information on the frontend. **I want to know if is possible to do this in mongodb** because I couldn't find a way to do it on their documentation or any other example here. Otherwise I might need to do it in the frontend (not a good idea...so I could have around 7k results or more on this array...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the aggregation framework should get you what you want.

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
{$unwind:'$checkins'},
{
    $project: {
        id: 1,
        'checkins.createdAt' : 1, 
        newDate : {
            $add : [ new Date(0), {
                $multiply : [ "$checkins.createdAt", 1000 ]
            }]
        }
    }
},
{$project : {
    year: {$year: "$newDate"},
    month: {$month: "$newDate"}
}},
{$group: {_id:{year:"$year", month:"$month"}, count:{$sum:1}}},
{$group: {_id:{year:"$_id.year"}, monthTotals: { $push:  { month: "$_id.month", count: "$count" } }}}
])
```

This produces documents like the following:

```
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "year" : NumberInt(2016)
    }, 
    "monthTotals" : [
        {"month" : NumberInt(1),"count" : NumberInt(2)}
        {"month" : NumberInt(2),"count" : NumberInt(3)}
    ]
}
```

The second step (first $project step) may need to be adjusted depending on how your date since epoch value is stored, but this should get you generally what you need.

There's not a way to get the data exactly as you've outlined without some post processing of the results, but it should be simple enough to modify the result.

Comment: Thanks @anztenney. This is definitely the way to go. Something weird is happening with the Dates (are stored as a String and I am having problems using the parseInt on the fly) but I'll deal with this myself.

Comment: If you need help just post the format here in the comments.